# Creating .NET Core REST API with embedded database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to create a .NET Core REST API which will contain an embedded database (possibly .mdf file) and still deploy it on other OS like Linux? I know that SQL Server can be installed on Linux but can this be done silently within the application's installation program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of different options. Some that you might want to consider:

1. [SqlLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) (relational)
2. [LiteDb](http://www.litedb.org) (nosql)
3. [DBreeze](https://github.com/hhblaze/DBreeze) (key-value)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend LiteBD, we've had tons of issues with concurrency. "File is in use by another process" all over the place.